# How to get profile page with onetoone field to User

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Suppose I have a

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,parent_link=True,primary_key=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

How can I get an object of Profile with given user id in view?

I'm new to Django. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well once you have a user profile for that user you should be able to accomplish this like so. If you need help creating the profiles, template calls, or URL mapping let me know.

```
   from yourapp.models import Profile

   def get_profile(request, user_id):
        context ={}
        profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=user_id)
        context['userprofile'] = profile
        return  render (request, 'your_template.html', context,)
```

Comment: {{ userprofile }} is how you would put it in your HTML file

Answer (score 3):

Given the user, you can just do `user.profile`.